# how to make click event on material design pack icon in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

I'm using material design pack icon in my WPF system. is it possible to make something like click event on the icon. its like when we click on the icon it will go to the page we want (something like button).

this is my code at WPF WINDOWS

```
 <ListViewItem Height="60">
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                   <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Man" Height="20" Width="25" Margin="10"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnSalesman" Click="btnSalesman_Click" Content="Salesman" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="10"/>
          </StackPanel>
 </ListViewItem>
```

I'm using both button and icon (and I need both) the thing is I need when user click on the icon or anywhere inside the stackpanel it will also act like my button click event. Is it possible ? or I need to use other icon ?

Comment: Have you try it? Just move `Click="btnSalesman_Click"` to `materialDesign:PackIcon` and then read more about MVVM ([here](http://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/) for example)

Comment: if I move the click event to `materialDesign:PackIcon` it will give an error something like `the member "click" does not recognized`

Comment: You should really learn MVVM and how to setup a binding to a command in a viewmodel, than continue to use code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MouseDown event defined in MaterialDesignPack package.

```
 <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="MapMarkerMinus" Height="20" Width="25" Margin="10" MouseDown="UIElement_OnMouseEnter"/>
```

Comment: does `MouseDown Event` applicable for touchscreen system ? because I'm doing this for something like touchscreen system

Comment: for touch screen you can try touchDown event which triggers event when that icon is touched

Comment: If you don't care to use Wpf kind of like WinForm this answer is fine, for the rest who want to dive into wpf world stay away from this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You better place the icon into a DataTemplate and apply the template to the button; templating and styling are both aspects where WPF shine.

From the top of my head (not tested):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonContentTemplate">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Man" Height="20" Width="25" Margin="10"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
```

Then you can apply the template to one or more buttons:

```
<Button ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonContentTemplate}" 
        Content="Salesman"/>
```

Comment: I've try your answer but it seems like it didn't work for me. Thank you anyway for your time :)